GIT remove Upstream-branch / Webserver shows Data from another folder
I have 2 folders with same code on a webserver.

folder for domain A
folder for domain B

So now, it goes crazzy! If I start domain B in a Browser, it shows me the data of folder 1. How can it be? i do not know why an how i can revert it.
This ist my history:

I made a copy of Data of folder 1 to folder 2
i created a new branch NEWBRANCH and pushed it.
Because i got an error, which show me this i have to do: git push --set-upstream origin NEWBRANCH
I did it, but then the problem from the beginning comes across.
If i change something in folder 2, Domain A shows the changing
If i change something in folder 1, Domain A shows the changing

Why does they use only the one folder?
If i make a changing in data in folder 2, my domain B has to show it and my NEWBRANCH has to save the changings.
What can i do? any idea?
I wrote that --set-upstream is very old and will not use anymore.

Sounds like a webserver configuration issue and not a Git issue. Git is neither a webserver nor a deployment tool.
